# declare a variable with interface type and initialize with concrete type, when will the concrete class will be loaded

Tags: java, class, classloader

here is the sample code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/user")
public class JsonSampleController {

    @GetMapping
    public User getUser() {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Car();
        return new User("y", 4);
    }
}
```

after the application is started, only `Vehicle` is loaded into JVM(result of -verbose:class), does `Car` will be loaded at runtime?

Comment: You already know `-verbose:class`, so how about running `getUser` and see if `Car` gets loaded yourself? Also, why does this matter to you?

Comment: @Sweeper just curious why  `Car` is loaded in runtime instead of starting time,  Is it a good reason to post this question？

Comment: "Why" is an unclear question - it is unclear what kind of answer will satisfy you. Is a quote from the language/JVM specification satisfy you? i.e. "because the spec says so".

Comment: @Sweeper can you show me the quote in specification? thanks

Comment: Oops, I got confused class loading with class initialisation, which the spec leaves more room for implementation details. Anyway, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34263422/5133585).